# XmlResourceParser and loading view

Tags: java, android, xml, view, load

I have layout resource, which is returned as XmlResourceParser object. How I can load it to the activty? I am looking for something similar as SetContentView function, which loads local xml files.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6575965/383905

Comment: [Load resource layout from another apk][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324253/load-resource-layout-from-another-apk/13218517#13218517