# Load resource (layout) from another apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, xml-parsing, layout-inflater

I am wondering if it is possible to load a layout xml file from another apk. I know how to get access to another applications resources, but i am unsure how to load an xml if its even possible.

Would I have to parse the xml if I wanted to set that layout as a view using layout inflater?

Sort of like these steps...

1. Use XmlPullParser.setInput to "load" the XML file
2. Convert it to an AttributeSet
3. Create a View from this AttributeSet
4. use setContentView(View) in your Activity

I guess what i am asking, is this even possible? Like I said, i know how to access resources. But how would i access the layout xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I managed to pull the layouts, and i add it to my viewflipper, however, there it is loaded as blank.

```
Resources packageResources;
Context packageContext;
try
{   
    packageResources = pm.getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
    packageContext = this.createPackageContext(packageName,  Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE + Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);                
}
catch(NameNotFoundException excep)
{
    // the package does not exist. move on to see if another exists.
}

Class layoutClass;
try
{
   // using reflection to get the layout class inside the R class of the package
   layoutClass = packageContext.getClassLoader().loadClass(packageName + ".R$layout");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException excep1)
{
   // Less chances that class won't be there.
}

for( Field layoutID : layoutClass.getFields() )
{
   try
   {
       int id = layoutID.getInt(layoutClass);
       XmlResourceParser xmlResourceLayout = packageResources.getLayout(id);

       View v = new View(this, Xml.asAttributeSet(xmlResourceLayout));

       this.viewFlipper.addView(v);                 
    }
    catch (Exception excep)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

I get no errors, and i debugged and checked. The layout IDs are correct. However, in my viewFlipper its just blank. No warnings or errors i can find.

Finally got the solution... Have posted it below,

[Load resource (layout) from another apk dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218819/load-resource-layout-from-another-apk-dynamically/13221270#13221270)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you're having trouble, rather create your own question and reference this one as necessary.