# Load resource (layout) from another apk dynamically

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, resources

I managed to pull the layouts, and i add it to my viewflipper, however, there it is loaded as blank.

The code is,

```
Resources packageResources;
Context packageContext;
try
{   
    packageResources = pm.getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
    packageContext = this.createPackageContext(packageName,     Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE + Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);                
 }
 catch(NameNotFoundException excep)
 {
     // the package does not exist. move on to see if another exists.
 }

 Class layoutClass;
 try
 {
       // using reflection to get the layout class inside the R class of the package
       layoutClass = packageContext.getClassLoader().loadClass(packageName + ".R$layout");
 }
 catch (ClassNotFoundException excep1)
 {
     // Less chances that class won't be there.
 }

 for( Field layoutID : layoutClass.getFields() )
 {
    try
    {
        int id = layoutID.getInt(layoutClass);
        XmlResourceParser xmlResourceLayout = packageResources.getLayout(id);

        View v = new View(this, Xml.asAttributeSet(xmlResourceLayout));

        this.viewFlipper.addView(v);                 
    }
    catch (Exception excep)
   {
    continue;
   }
}
```

I get no errors, and i debugged and checked. The layout IDs are correct. However, in my viewFlipper its just blank. No warnings or errors i can find.

Comment: In view hierarchy, it showed the views are there, however the children of each view is not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it.... Its actually simple !!!!

Here is what i did...

1. In the target apk, there is only resources and layouts with no application or activity code. I created a class,

   ```
   public final class ViewExtractor
   {
       private static final int NUMBER_OF_LAYOUTS = 5;

       public static View[] getAllViews(Context context)
       {
           View[] result = new View[ViewExtractor.NUMBER_OF_LAYOUTS];

           result[0] = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_0, null);
           result[1] = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_1, null);
           result[2] = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_2, null);
           result[3] = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_3, null);
           result[4] = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_4, null);

           return result;
       }
    }
   ```

Then in my current application, I modified my earlier code. The modification takes place once package has been verified to exist.

```
        // If the package exists then get the resources within it.
        // Use the method in the class to get the views.
        Class<?> viewExtractor;
        try
        {
            viewExtractor = packageContext.getClassLoader().loadClass(packageName + ".ViewExtractor");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException excep)
        {
            continue;
        }

        View[] resultViews;
        try
        {
            Method m = viewExtractor.getDeclaredMethod("getAllViews", Context.class);

            resultViews= (View[])m.invoke(null, new Object[]{packageContext});

            for( View v : resultViews)
            {
                this.viewFlipper.addView(v);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            excep.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: but.. how to use this class? Please could you provide an example or a link to a sample project? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are not inflating a layout. You are creating an empty `View` and adding it to your `ViewFlipper`.

Comment: How to inflate the layout using XmlResourceParser ? And if one cannot then (which is i have searched and most are saying not possible) then is there any other way of using the layout of another apk and incorporating it in your application ?

Comment: @SiddharthNaik: "How to inflate the layout using XmlResourceParser ?" -- I am not aware that this is possible. "is there any other way of using the layout of another apk and incorporating it in your application ?" -- I can think of no easy way to do this off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently doing this. It only works if a know the packageName of activity or fragment from the .apk that should provide the layout hierarchy (I call this foreign context). And you need to know the name of the layout you want to inflate (e.g. R.layout.mylayout -> "mylayout")

```
Context c = createPackageContext(foreignPackageName,
    Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE|Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY); //create foreign context
int resId = c.getResources.getIdentifier(mylayoutName,"layout",foreignPackageName); 
LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); //Inflater for foreign context
View myLayout = myInflater.inflate(resId,null,false); //do not attach to a root view
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  It absolutely works - but with a caveat.  I'm testing on Android 6.0.1, and via debugging, I can see that the layout is indeed inflated - along with all of its children, but the children won't display on the screen.  It must have something to do with those Views being constructed using the foreign context.  I wrote some code to crudely clone the foreign layout and its children -- using my current context -- and displaying that cloned layout works.

Comment: Perhaps you can share the code you had to write to make it work? I can't yet put my finger on why it didn't work.

Comment: Another thing to mention (although it does not seem to be the problem Code4aliving describes): ID collisions. As you know IDs like R.id.mytext are translated via project specific R.java to simple integer IDs. So maybe you will have collisions with IDs of your hosting (main) app's recources. You can mitigate or completly avoid those by not using getActivtiy().findById but using layout.findById on the innermost possible layout. I think this way the discovery process has also to be faster.