# Can I use external XML files in for layouts in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-xml

This might be a silly question, but I would like to generate a layout xml file for android on the server, and when the user presses a button, the xml file is loaded into the android app.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Theoretical question: load external XML-Layout file in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575965/theoretical-question-load-external-xml-layout-file-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible. The layout inflator documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29):

From the documentation the constructor:

```
public View inflate (XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root)
```

states:

> Important   For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on
>   pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it
>   is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser
>   over a plain XML file at runtime.

Why not just create the xml for the views and build them into the application? That is how Android Apps are typically done. If you want to support totally dynamically generated screens then it is going to be a lot of work. You could do it by developing your own layout sytax, and creating a view that knows how to dynamically render a view from that syntax. Essentially you would need to reinvent the layout inflator thats built into the OS.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. i couldn't find the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that, you can create any view you want, programmatically, without writing them in an xml file.